# New condition of an unbiasedness

Tags: parameter-estimation

The usual unbiasedness condition of an estimand $g(\theta)$ is this $$E_\theta[\delta(X)]=g(\theta).$$
Here $g(\theta)$ is a real valued function over $\Omega$ whose
value is to be estimated. This is already contained in the word
estimand. On the other hand $\delta(X)$ is called estimator.

I have no exact hint why this latter is more general, it is just my intuition. This is the core of my question, whether and why the following is more general:

I've considered another condition $$P_\theta[\delta(X)<g(\theta)]=P_\theta[\delta(X)>g(\theta)].$$

What is the relationship between these 2 conditions; is the latter one more general?

Comment: What does $\delta$ mean here?

Comment: @kimchilover Real valued function from $\Omega$ whose value is to be estimated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this info, and a hint about why you think the "latter one is more general".